# creating tcp server for http server (node.js)

Tags: node.js, http, tcp

first of all I'm really sorry for asking such stupid question but i'm really new to programming and have no idea what i'm doing. I'm learning by reading books and tutorials.

so my question is

when do i actually need to create tcp server? I know tcp server is connection-oriented transport protocol used for reliable delivery of packets, but like for example, when i'm making a simple web app for chat, I'm using http and it seeems working fine without creating tcp server.. but that wouldn't make sense because http actually runs over tcp right?

I started learning server-side programming about a month ago.. and i'm just really lost.

ps. i'm using node.js and socket.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Express](http://expressjs.com/) might suit your needs though I don't fully understand your problem. TCP is a protocol

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/hello', function(req, res){
   res.send('Hello World');
 });
var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

Comment: sorry i'm not good at phrasing questions. so what i meant was, in that example case, var server = app.listen(3000, function) is making http server right? because express is made to ease http requests and stuff. but then where does tcp server come into play in here. I'm talking in purely programmatic sense not a logical structure or whatnot. Like if I wanted to actually run http (which is application layer) don't i need to also create tcp (transport layer) somewhere in the coding? or is it just automatically taken care of by the browser? Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is taken care of by the http server.

Comment: Thanks. okay then when do we actually need to create TCP server?

Comment: No, just create the http server by express and proceed.